# Update a Collection to add a new Field with the value of another Field of same Collection in bulk mood

Tags: mongodb, bulkupdate

I am bit new in mongoDB. Let's say I have a collection having a structure like this:

```
mycoll
{ 
    _id, 
    col1 -> NumberInt
}
```

And there are thousands of documents already in the collection. Now, I want to update every document of the collection to add a new field(i.e. **col2**) of NumberInt type whose value will be same as the value of field **col1**. Is there any way to do that in bulk mood not running the update command for each document? I am currently using mongoDB of version 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongo updateMany() Functionality.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   <filter>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ],
     hint:  <document|string>        // Available starting in MongoDB 4.2.1
   }
)
```

Check this link for further detail,
[Update Many documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)